# Не работает форма отправки!

Tags: php

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться с формой отправки! Браузер прописывает ошибку на странице, и при нажатие отправить сервер отправляет письмо,  но оно почему-то пустое без содержания лишь прописывает переменные $str,  $svr, $mavt, $work .

```
<?php

$sender_Name = $_POST['senderName'];
$sender_Email = $_POST['senderEmail'];
$phone_namber = $_POST['phone'];
$marka_avto = $_POST['marka'];
$message_email = $_POST['message'];

$tel = "Телефон:"; $str = iconv('cp1251', 'utf-8', $tel); 
$eml = "Электронная почта:"; $svr = iconv('cp1251', 'utf-8', $eml); 
$m_av = "Марка автомобиля:"; $mavt = iconv('cp1251', 'utf-8', $m_av);
$wo_rk = "Что нужно сделать:"; $work = iconv('cp1251', 'utf-8', $wo_rk);

$email = 'Avtoclub-Kazan.ru';
$to = 'arty21.ru@yandex.ru';
$subject = 'Заказ';
$msg = "$sender_Name  $svr $sender_Email.\n" .
"$str $phone_namber\n" .
"$mavt $marka_avto\n" .
"$work $message_email";

    $headers= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
    $headers .= "From:".$email."\n\r";
    mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);       
?>

  <div id="botton">
  <a href="#contactForm" class="botton-font">Запись Автосервис</a> 
  </div>

 <h2>Шлите нам весточку</h2>
<ul>
  <li>
    <label for="senderName">Ваше Имя</label>
  <input type="text" name="senderName" id="senderName" class="sender" placeholder="Пожалуйста введите свое имя" required="required" maxlength="40" />
</li>

<li>
  <label for="senderEmail">Ваш электронный адрес</label>
  <input type="email" name="senderEmail" id="senderEmail" class="sender" placeholder="Пожалуйста введите свой электронный адрес"  maxlength="50" />
</li>

  <li>
  <label for="phone">Ваш телефон</label>
  <input type="number" name="phone" id="phone" class="sender"   placeholder="Пожалуйста введите свой телефон" required="required" maxlength="20" />
</li>

<li>
  <label for="marka">Марка и Модель А/М</label>
  <input type="text" name="marka" id="marka" class="sender" placeholder="Пожалуйста введите марку и модель авто" required="required" maxlength="200" />
</li>

<li>
  <label for="message" style="padding-top: .5em;">Что сделать?</label>
  <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Введите свою информацию о том что надо сделать" required="required" cols="80" rows="10" maxlength="10000"></textarea>
</li>

</ul>

<div id="formButtons">
  <input type="submit" id="sendMessage" name="sendMessage" value="Отправить" />
  <input type="button" id="cancel" name="cancel" value="Отменить" />
 </div>
```

</form>

```
<div id="sendingMessage" class="statusMessage"><p>Отправка сообщения. Пожалуйста, подождите...</p></div>
<div id="successMessage" class="statusMessage"><p>Спасибо за отправленное нам сообщение! Мы свяжемся с Вами в ближайшее время.</p></div>
<div id="failureMessage" class="statusMessage"><p>Существует проблема отправки сообщения. Пожалуйста, попробуйте еще раз.</p></div>
<div id="incompleteMessage" class="statusMessage"><p>Пожалуйста, заполните все поля формы перед отправкой.</p></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Не те переменные в $msg собираете. Надо не $phone_namber, а $tel. И еще половины переменных в вашем коде не нашел, возможно поэтому и ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте. Не знаю, возможно у Вас опечатка, или же я слепой: Вы <form> открыли?
Закрывающий тег я вижу, но вот начало идет с

```
<div id="botton">
  <a href="#contactForm" class="botton-font">Запись Автосервис</a> 
</div>
```

да и соответствующего echo в php-коде я не нашел.